# Cohomology groups of a non-degenerate algebraic variety.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X\subset\mathbb{P}^{n}$ be an algebraic variety. Let us suppose that $X$ is non-degenerate (it is not contained in any hyperplane of $\mathbb{P}^{n}$). I have read that (at least for curves) the natural map 
$$
H^{0}(\mathbb{P}^{n},\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n}}(1))\rightarrow H^{0}(X,\mathcal{O}_{X}(1))
$$
is injective, i.e. $H^{0}(\mathbb{P}^{n},\mathcal{I}_{X,\mathbb{P}^{n}}(1))=0$, where $\mathcal{I}_{X,\mathbb{P}^{n}}$ is the sheaf of modules induced by the ideal of $X\subset\mathbb{P}^{n}$. I don't know why this is true. I would appreciate if you could tell me why it holds or if you could recommend me a book where this is shown.

Comment: This map is the restriction of linear forms on $\mathbf P^n$ to $X$. But if such a form restricts to zero, then $X$ is contained in the zero locus of that form, which is a hyperplane. (By the way, you left out the twist by $O(1)$ in the cohomology group after "i.e."

Comment: @Nefertiti Excuse me, do you know of any book where I can find this kind of basic properties of cohomology? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just because $H^{0}(\mathbb{P}^{n},\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n}}(1))$ is given by linear functions, so if one were in the kernel of $H^{0}(\mathbb{P}^{n},\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n}}(1))\rightarrow H^{0}(X,\mathcal{O}_{X}(1))$ it would precisely mean that it vanishes on $X$, so $X$ would be contained in the corresponding hyperplane.

Comment: Excuse me, do you know of any book where I can find this kind of basic properties of cohomology? Thank you!

Comment: Pretty much any book on algebraic geometry ; I guess the Hartshorne is a good standard choice.